# How to read acct file?

Tags: c, linux

I turned on accounting. But I'm unable to read it. Here is the code

```
/* my_acct.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/acct.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *file_acct = "acct_test.txt";
    int choice= 0;
    if(argc > 1)
        choice = strcmp(argv[1], "ON") ? 0 : 1;

    if(choice) {
        if(acct(file_acct) != 0){     // on success: 0
                perror("acct");
        }
    } else {
        if(acct(NULL) != 0) {
                perror("acct");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run my program `my_acct ON`, process terminations logging into given file(`acct_test.txt`). But I'm unable to read the file. It looks like it is writing in binary format.
How to read `acct_test.txt` file? Or I have to change my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dump-acct` command from `psacct` package.